# XSL-FO - Center Text not working

Tags: alignment, center, xsl-fo, text-alignment

In my XSL-FO, I am having problems centering text as it breaks the footnote-line2 into 2 sentences as opposed to going the full length of the page and then breaking the sentence once it runs out of room. See graphics below.

I have this code:

```
    <fo:block font-size="9pt" text-align="center">
        <xsl:value-of select="footnote-line1"/>
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block font-size="9pt" text-align="center">
        <xsl:value-of select="footnote-line2"/>
    </fo:block>
```

Here is my XML:

```
    <footnote-line1>This verification of XXXXXX is self-generated and is produced by John Smith from our secure website.</footnote-line1>
    <footnote-line2>If there are any questions regarding the information contained in this letter, you may contact the Joe Blow at his office at the contact information noted above.</footnote-line2>
```

Which generates this output:[image]:

Unfortunately, the above image is not what I want as it is doing a paragraph break after the word "you".

This 2 images below are the output I am hoping to get. The first image I achieved that was by shrinking down the font to 6pt, but I don't want to shrink the font down.

Option 1) Alternate solution, but would rather not shrink down the font size

[image]

Option 2) Optimal solution without shrinking the font

[image]

How would I achieve option #2?

Updated with colored backgrounds and both are the same length for the first and second footnotes:
[image]

Here is the full XSL-FO document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root font-family="Times Roman" font-size="9pt">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="main-voe"
                    margin-top="15mm" margin-bottom="15mm" margin-left="25mm" margin-right="25mm" page-width="215mm" page-height="279mm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="1.0in" margin-bottom="1.0in"/>
                    <fo:region-before extent="1.0in" margin-top="1.0in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="main-voe" initial-page-number="1">
                <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before" font-size="9pt">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="enrolment/address-dept-info"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:static-content>
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-size="9pt">
                    <fo:block font-weight="bold" linefeed-treatment="preserve" space-after="9pt">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="enrolment/letter"/>
                    </fo:block>
                    <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" font-weight="bold" space-after="9pt">
                        Notes:      
                    </fo:block>
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="enrolment/student-info/student-notes/student-notes-details"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="enrolment/signature"/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
        <!-- This sections builds the header information at the top of the page  -->
    <xsl:template match="address-dept-info">
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
            <fo:table-column column-width="25mm" padding="0"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="100mm"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="85mm"/>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                            Logo info
                        </fo:block>                        
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block linefeed-treatment='preserve'
                            white-space-collapse='false'><xsl:value-of select="address1"/></fo:block>
                        <fo:block linefeed-treatment='preserve'
                            white-space-collapse='false'><xsl:value-of select="address2"/></fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block linefeed-treatment='preserve'
                            white-space-collapse='false'>
                            <xsl:value-of select="dept/dept-name"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>       
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="student-info">
        <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" space-after="9pt">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                <fo:table-column column-width="5mm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="80mm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="100mm"/> 
                <fo:table-body>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//student-info/student-program/student-program-details"/>
                </fo:table-body>    
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="student-notes/student-notes-details">
        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
    </xsl:template>    
    <xsl:template match="signature">
        <fo:block linefeed-treatment='preserve' space-after="9pt">
            Sincerely,
        </fo:block> 
        <fo:block linefeed-treatment='preserve' space-after="12pt">
            <xsl:value-of select="first-name"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="last-name"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="position"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="9pt" text-align="center" background-color="grey">
            <xsl:value-of select="//letter/footnote-line1"/>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="9pt" text-align="center" background-color="yellow">
                <xsl:value-of select="//letter/footnote-line2"/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="letter">
        <fo:block linefeed-treatment='preserve' text-align="center">
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks
Cheers

Comment: What are you using to output your XSL-FO (FOP, Antenna House, RenderX, etc.)? I've actually found the opposite problem more often; I want text to balance and it won't. But I'm not sure if I've seen that with centered text, specifically.

Comment: @Christina I am using Apache FOP

Comment: It looks the region display area is limited for this footnote-line elements. Please check its parent element have you set any left-right space or indent and so on. Use background color to notice that what is actual area to display those contents.

Comment: @NavinRawat
I have updated the background with different colors and width of both the first line and the second line are the same length.  See graphic above

Comment: @MoxieC: Can you show us a complete FO document that exhibits the problem? Try to make it as small as possible. That would make it easier to help.

Comment: Navin is likely correct. Margins are inherited into the footnote area.

Comment: @MoxieC: Please confirm have you put background color on footnote-line1/footnote-line2 element?

Comment: @NavinRawat yes I have added the full background color

Comment: @mzjn Added a complete FO document that shows the problem as you have requested.

Comment: @MoxieC: You have posted an XSLT stylesheet, but what I asked for was the FO document that you get when you apply the stylesheet to the XML source document. I'm sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with FOP and you get the answer you get. Sorry. It's FOP. You could report as a bug.

Using RenderX XEP you get the answer you want and should rightly expect.

[image]

Comment: These aren't really footnotes. The XML just say footnotes when really it is just 2 sentences that need to be centered.